# Find by value in nested array of objects in array of objects - large dataset

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, optimization, for-loop

I have large number of objects in myArray (300+). each object under user I have more objects about 10 each.

I want to return objects containing specific user.id (e.g. user.id = 17)

I can do this with a for loop within for loop. However because of the size of data set... browser crashes... I wonder what would be the best way of doing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/vtrnn6z9/

```
 var myArray = [{
     id: "453453",
     user: [{
         id: "17",
         name: "sdfsd"
     }, {
         id: "45",
         name: "dfsdf"
     }, {
         id: "46",
         name: "sdfsd"
     }]
 }, {
     id: "547645",
     user: [{
         id: "17",
         name: "sdfsd"
     }, {
         id: "35",
         name: "dfsdf"
     }, {
         id: "48",
         name: "sdf"
     }]
 }, {
     id: "564654",
     user: [{
         id: "5",
         name: "sdfsd"
     }, {
         id: "48",
         name: "fthf"
     }, {
         id: "35",
         name: "sdfsdf"
     }]
 }];

// my Solution
 var siteIDs = [];
 var userId = '17';

 for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     var user = myArray[i].user;

     for (var r = 0; r < user.length; r++) {
         var someId = user[r].id;
         if (someId == userId) {
             siteIDs.push(myArray[i]);
         }
         var someId = null;
     }

 }

 console.log(siteIDs);
```

Comment: That's not a very big list. I have a hard time believing that it would cause a crash.

Comment: Why you push `myArray[r]`?

Comment: @squint yes... I am just showing sample data... actual data coming from a json feed

Comment: @lesha oops I made a mistake!!

Comment: @montecristo i recommend you to use `forEach` to loop arrays. It's (should be) faster, and you get rid of some variables

Comment: How do you know that only because of the size of the data, the browser crashes?

Comment: @MonteCristo: No, I mean an array of 300 items, each of which having a sub-array of 10 items isn't a very big list. Any browser will handle that easily. The cause of the crash is most certainly elsewhere.

Comment: Yes.... It's the second loop that killed it all... but when I dig around found out that one of my other scripts actually multiplying the data by factor of... not adding the additional data in to it... causing the site to crash...

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to push `myArray[i]` instead of `myArray[r]`

```js
var groups, siteIDs, value, userGroup;

groups = [
  {
    id: "453453",
    user: [
      {
        id: "17",
        name: "sdfsd"
      },
      {
        id: "45",
        name: "dfsdf"
      },
      {
        id: "46",
        name: "sdfsd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "547645",
    user: [
      {
        id: "17",
        name: "sdfsd"
      },
      {
        id: "35",
        name: "dfsdf"
      },
      {
        id: "48",
        name: "sdf"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "564654",
    user: [
      {
        id: "5",
        name: "sdfsd"
      },
      {
        id: "48",
        name: "fthf"
      },
      {
        id: "35",
        name: "sdfsdf"
      }
    ]
  }
];

siteIDs = [];
value = '17';

groups.forEach(function(group) {
  userGroup = group.user;
  
  userGroup.forEach(function(user) {
    if (user.id === value) {
      siteIDs.push(group);
    }
  });
});

userGroup = null;

console.log(siteIDs);
```

Comment: Yes... I made a mistake... but doesn't answer my question though

Comment: simple `for` is [much better](http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/216) in performance, and should be noted that `forEach` works [>= IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility)